# Can't find a verb to match this object 「このさわぎを」

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

> **このさわぎを**戸川先生やむこうにいた生徒たちまでもが固唾をのんで見つめていることに気がついた関口は、まる子と神谷先生をもう一度きっとにらんだ。
>   Sekiguchi, who had noticed teacher Togawa and even the students on the other side holding their breath and staring、once again scowled hard at Maruko and teacher Kamiya.

I can't fit このさわぎを into my translation. There seems to be no verb that matches with "this uproar".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it this way:

> このさわぎ**を**戸川先生**や**（むこうにいた）生徒たちまでも**が**（固唾をのんで）**見つめている**・・・

「ＯをＳ１やＳ２までもがＶしている」 = "S1 and even S2 are V-ing O"

このさわぎ is the object for 見つめている.